# Java rounding a double truncates zeroes

Tags: java

I have below logic that rounds a double value to 2 decimal places:

```
public double round(double value, int places) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();    
}
```

It is working for most of the cases but fails to round the result to 2 decimal places in some cases, below is an example for it.

If I call this method using code `round(12.503, 2)`, I need the result as `12.50` because I need result in 2 decimal places, but I am getting output as `12.5`

Please help me how to fix this case.

Comment: You are mixing up 2 thing: 1. The double value and 2. how to represent a double value. The double value itself has no format. If you want to output your double with 2 decimal places you need to use a class that can format double number output. (String.format for example)

Comment: It depends on how you format the output, not the double value.

Comment: i.e: use `new DecimalFormat("#.00")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ***not*** getting the result as `12.5`.

You are receiving back a double.

Then, you have chosen some arbitrary method of displaying that double, (which you have told us nothing about,) and based on the results of applying that method you *think* that its value is `12.5`.

You see, the thing with doubles is that they cannot be thought of as having a fixed number of decimal digits.  (Or, more accurately, the number of decimal digits that they have is so huge, that nobody ever wants to see them all.)  So, in all likelihood the *actual* value of the double that you receive, without any bias introduced by various methods of displaying it, is something akin to 12.5000000... But you need to choose the right method of displaying it in order to see what it is.  If the method that you chose simply strips trailing zeros, then you may be left with the impression that you are missing a trailing zero.  Or 10 trailing zeros.

So, you need to convert it back to `BigDecimal` before you can make any assumptions as to what result you are getting.

Comment: A double has a mantissa of 53 bits. That means it can represent about 15 significant decimal digits. Whether that really is "huge" is a matter of interpretation, but your "12.500..." example already has 20 digits. Anyway, the number of trailing zeroes is a property of the decimal representation, not the double itself, so 12.5 = 12.50 = 12.500 ... And since the BigDecimal already did the rounding, I'd expect that the value of the returned double in the OP's code example is indeed exactly 12.5.

Comment: @Hoopje the significance that I attach to saying that a double number is 12.500000000000 and not just 12.5 is to show that it is quite accurately 12.5 as opposed to, say, 12.500000000010.

Answer (score 4):

A double in Java represents a mathematical number where 12.50 is the same number as 12.5. How many digits of a number are shown is a concern of converting it to a string, not of the number itself.

So better do the rounding when you convert the number to a string for output, e.g.:

```
System.out.printf("%5.2f", value);
```